# Can anyone tell me information about this uniform?

Tags: world-war-one, italy, italian

[image]

This is my Great-Great Grandfather during WWI in the Royal Italian Army. Looking for any hints that his uniform could tell me about his type of service

Comment: Hello and welcome to History:SE. Can't help directly, but this link might be a starting point. Judging from the collar, he was in the RE (Kings) Brigade, if that's any help.  http://miniaturasmilitaresalfonscanovas.blogspot.com/2011/12/la-primera-guerra-mundial-italia-por.html?m=1

Comment: Thank you for your help! I’m looking at the solid dark color of his collar and thinking it may fit with 3-4 (Piemonte), 7-8 (Cuneo), 23-24 (Como), or 51-52 (Alpi.) from the chart on your link. Those are all in Northern Italy, whereas I know him to have been from the province of Avellino in Campania, Italy so I’m unsure if he was stationed elsewhere, such as one of those previously listed areas or if his collar/epaulets should reflect where in Italy he was from

Comment: Yes, it's difficult without more information. I tried to look at his cap badge, but the resolution is just not good enough, it could be almost anything. Hope you can find more information, maybe older relatives might know something? Good luck.